# How to start debugging this Java code?

Tags: java, calculator

I'm very new at programming, and I have no idea why this doesn't work.

What I want to do is like:

```
pmmd = plus - minus - multi.. - divide..
```

code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyCalculator{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner ScanN = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner ScanT = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double fnum, snum, answer;
    Boolean pmmd;
    System.out.println("Enter First Number");
    fnum = ScanN.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
    snum = ScanN.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter minus, plus, multi or divide");
    pmmd = ScanT.nextBoolean();
    Object plus = "+";
    Object minus = "-";
    Object multi = "*";
    if(pmmd.equals(plus))  {
        answer = fnum + snum;
    }
    else if(pmmd.equals(minus))  {
            answer = fnum - snum;
        }
    else if(pmmd.equals(multi))  {
            answer = fnum * snum;
        }
    else  {
        answer = fnum / snum;
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, we can't tell you why it doesn't work until you tell us what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
System.out.println("Enter minus, plus, multi or divide");
pmmd = ScanT.nextBoolean();
```

A boolean is about true/false. But "+" is a string, not a true/false value!

You want a **String**, like

```
String operator = scanT.next();
```

Beyond that, there are many other things that don't make much sense in your code. For example this:

```
Object plus = "+";
```

should be

```
String plus = "+";
```

for example.

And you would rather do something like:

```
switch(operatorGivenByUser) {
  case "+":
```

...

instead of putting up such an if/else chain.

I know, it seems hard, but the point is: when you write code, be sure to understand what each line is doing. If you don't understand it - read about it.

Beyond that, there are more subtle problems like:

- Bad naming: "pmmd" says nothing about the intent of that variable. I renamed it to "operator"; or "operatorGivenByUser" - which gives you at least a hint what the content of that variable is about!
- Bad naming (II): you should read about java coding style conventions. Variable names start lowercase; so it is `scanT` ; not `ScanT`. (where again; that name actually says nothing, just call it `scanner` for example)
- Insufficient checking: when doing divisions, make sure that the denominator is **not** 0.

Comment: And at division you should check if `snum == 0` to aviod an exception.